# python3 multiprocess.pool.terminate() does not kill processes

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to execute tasks in parallel and if any of the task exit with an error, all the processes should be stopped also and exit. Here is my code

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time, os, subprocess, sys

def run_pipeline(value):
    pid = os.getpid()
    if value == 7:
        print("Death process (%d) 7 starts ..." % pid)
        r = subprocess.run('sleep 10', shell=True)
        print("Death process (%d) 7 ends ..." % pid)
        return value
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while time.perf_counter() < start + 100:
        print('ProcessID: %s @ value %s' % (str(pid),str(value)),end='\n',flush=True)
        r = subprocess.run('sleep 100', shell=True)
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run pipeline in parallel
    with mp.Pool(8) as pool:
        value = list(range(20))
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(run_pipeline, value):
            if r > 0:
                print('killed %d' % r)
                pool.terminate()
                pool.close()
                time.sleep(10)  # time to check process list for only one Python process running
                print('end of program')
                break
```

This code will exit when any of the small tasks throw an error. But all other processes are still executing if I use top to check in ubuntu terminal, until they finish normally.
According to python3 documentation, pool.terminate() should "Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work."(https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

I don't know what is wrong with my code.
My system is 16.04
My python is 3.5.2

Many thanks!

**Edits:**

Thank you all for your replies. That helped me to understand my problem better. I have also made the code complete. I apologize for asking the wrong questions. Indeed, `pool.terminate()` did stop all python subprocesses in the pool as expected. However, as you can tell from my code above (edited). In each python subprocess, subprocess is called to generate another subprocess in bash. Obviously, pool.terminate() does not stop any of these bash processes (you can use `pgrep "sleep"` to see these processes hanging there until then end, even though python processes are all gone).
Thus, my question should be like that, "Are there any way to stop these bash processes if any of the python subprocess go wrong?"

Thank you again!

Comment: This isn't a complete program, so it is difficult to tell what is wrong.  Make it a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete program that demonstrates `pool.terminate()` works correctly, at least on my Windows 10 system.  The `run_pipeline` function only returns if the work `value` is 7 (I have 8 processors), but they all stop once terminated:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def run_pipeline(value):
    if value == 7:
        time.sleep(.5)
        return 7
    start = time.perf_counter()
    while time.perf_counter() < start + 10:
        print(value,end=' ',flush=True)
        time.sleep(.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run pipeline in parallel
    with mp.Pool(8) as pool:
        value = list(range(20))
        for r in pool.imap_unordered(run_pipeline, value):
            print(f'killed{r}')
            pool.terminate()
            time.sleep(10)  # time to check process list for only one Python process running
            break
```

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 0 2 3 4 5 6 1 0 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 killed7
```

7 processes are running forever, the 8th gets a "7" and returns a result after 500ms.  That pool worker starts on work 8, but then all pool workers stop.  Task Manager showed 9 processes (main thread and 8 pool workers) until `terminate`, then only the main process was running.

Comment: Thank you very much! By studying your code, I understand the mechanism and figured out that I asked wrong questions!